# Java Out of Heap Space

Tags: java, jar

In my java program I am using text to speech to speak out numbers, after it speaks up around 150 numbers it goes out of heap space (when opened from JAR) I did try to increase the heap space too but still the problem persists.

## What all I tried:

Using batch scripting:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar Super_Brain Academy.jar
pause
```

[`Super_Brain Academy.jar` is the file name] but this still doesn't solve my problem as it increases the heap space only for the main JAR file and not the TTS(freeTTS).

I also tried to make a fat Jar and then do this, but the problem is when I make the fat JAR the TTS stops working and I am unable to listen to anything. I tried to make the fat JAR by [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-build-fat-jar-using) method. I also tried to make fat JAR from other methods given on stackoverflow but they were confusing and I could not understand them. I am a newbie(well you might have figured that out till now) and using Netbeans 8.

## Code

According to my knowledge I think that the error must be coming this code block which is in a separate java file:

```
   private static final String VOICENAME = "kevin16";
   
   VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
```

//Some code here..........

```
private void RandomjBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
//When the button is clicked it generates one random number according to the conditions and speaks it up
    Voice voice;
    voice = voiceManager.getVoice(VOICENAME);
    voice.allocate();

    //Some variable declarations and initializations along with set visible commmands were here(removed as irrevelant for the problem)

    for (g = 0; g==0;) {
        ran = (int) (Math.random() * (c)); // Random Number Creation Starts
      if(ran>=c/10){

           g = 1;
           //Some logic statements here

      }//IF ENDS  
      if(g!=0){
          if(num<0){
              num = num * (-1); // MAKING NUM ALWAYS +ve
          }
      }//if(g!-0) ends here  
    }//for loop ends
    d = d+ran;
    t4.setText("" + ran);
    voice.speak(t4.getText());
    listenanum.setText("" + d);
    listenanum.setVisible(false);
}
```

This <kbd>randomjB</kbd> is clicked again and again and that's when the problem occurs. (I have removed many lines from the above code so it may not practically make sense to you... but I have left only those lines which I feel are important)

For full code of randomjB check [this](http://pastebin.com/dYgGVwkx)

Comment: Mya be you are not releasing resources properly. Showing your code would help

Comment: Try fixing the memory leak in your code first before tweaking JVM options (Xmx, Xms, etc.)

Comment: @Dibya Which code? build.xml?

Comment: I suggest you memory profile the application in visualVM to see why it is using this amount of memory.  You could have a bug.

Comment: @EmanuelSaringan Are you sure there is memory leak because by default is just has 4 or 5 MB i thought that is not enough for tts... I also dont have any debugger to do that(i am using netbeans)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I will just check that out once

Comment: The default heap size is 1/4 of your main memory (unless you are using 32-bit windows JVM)  Setting it to 1 GB might be the same or even smaller than you were using.

Comment: The java code which you are using.

Comment: @dibya my code is too big so it wud be better if u tell me which part r u looking for ...!!! or else i will upload all of the code if u need

Comment: It will be very difficult to tell without looking into the code. You can start looking for the resources you can close/clean up. Try limiting scope of your variables. You may think towards optimizing the code.

Comment: Where do you change the value of g in the for loop?

Comment: @Crossfire Updated the code have a look, it was there in the main code, i removed all that because i was sort of sure that there is no such silly error, but anyways i did add the whole code link in case anyone wanted

Answer (score 0):

As per you comments I think it is an issue with the memory management.

I found [this](http://java-performance.com/) link very helpful. You can follow the same wherever it is applicable to make your program block memory.

After optimizing aslo if you get the same error message, you can go through [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/) link to learn how to increase the heap size.

Comment: I believe that there is nothing useful in http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/ link that you provided as that is what I am doing (via batch scripting, i am giving the cmd args) and still have the problem, and as far as the memory management is concerned... I will surely look into that

Comment: @DakshShah: You must have a java code to do some task right? As you are getting a `Java out of heap` error! My suggestion is to optimize your java code. Increase the heap size and give it a try. If the java code is not releasing resources in properly then you can't do much from batch file.

Comment: Ooh, now I get it am sorry I misunderstood... I will just add that code in the question too.